# Cannot test Xamarin ios App on device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have just created an xamarin ios app 'TestApp' for testing on iphone device. The same app created on xcode and deployed succuessfully on both iphone and simulator.
I have created an Apple Id using [this](https://appleid.apple.com/account?localang=en_US&appId=632&returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fidmsa.apple.com%2FIDMSWebAuth%2Flogin.html%3Flanguage%3DUS-EN%26rv%3D1%26path%3D%252Faccount%252F%26Env%3DUAT%26appIdKey%3D891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757#!&page=create) .Below image shows the the provisioning profile and signing identity i have created.

[image]

Bundle identifier of both mac and windows project are same also. i have followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=vsmac) for free provisioning. Appie Id is added to the visualstudio project using fastlane. But when i run this app on visualstudio2017, it just builds successfully; neither deploying to the iphone nor simulator; just builds and run button enables again .no more. How can i deploy the app on device?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you connected your Mac in Visual Studio?

Comment: yes. connected.

Comment: Are you able to select the Iphone in the dropdown?

Comment: yes. device connected to mac and able to select the device in dropdown

Comment: Have you checked deploy under configuration manager?

Comment: i have selected debug in dropdown of configuration by rightclicking project-properties in the bundle signing. platform choosed iphone

Comment: go to iTunes, does iTunes recognize the phone?

Comment: I have not checked that. i will check it now

Comment: yes. phone is showing in the Devices dropdown list in iTunes

Answer (score 0):

Now its working...Tools -> Extensions and Updates-> 'Mono Debugging For Visual Studio' was disabled. I Enabled it and program now  deploys to the device ..